# CSS3 Gradient flickers on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm playing around with a CSS3 Gradient and trying to move it in on mouseover. As you can see from this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aR9YV/), the CSS gradient appears on `:hover`; however, it seems to flickers a few times.

FYI, so far, this has been tested on `Chrome v30` / `Firefox v24` / `Safari v5.1`.

Separately, both have turned out to be working solutions, but combined, I get the flickering effect.

```
nav li {
    width: 90px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;

    background-position: -200px -200px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
    transition: background 1s ease-out;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-position: 200px 0;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%, rgba(96,96,96,0.2) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(96,96,96,0.2)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(96,96,96,0.2) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(96,96,96,0.2) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(96,96,96,0.2) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(96,96,96,0.2) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33ffffff', endColorstr='#33606060',GradientType=0 );
}
```

I've tried limiting the animation using `animation-iteration-count`, but as I've figured out, this only seems to work with animations and `@keyframes`. I've also read on a few different sites that 
`@keyframes` don't yet support CSS Gradient animation.

Comment: Kind of a cool effect. It would be difficult to get that if you wanted it!

Comment: Yes, this is very neat indeed. However, this is not what we are looking for. I guess that's a happy accident. However, I would like to get this working properly without using jQuery.

Comment: @ConorPender As you'll see from the anwser posted by Spudley, the effect comes from the offset value, which gives this flickering effect. Therefore, if it was a desired effect, it would be easily obtainable. Hope this gives you ideas in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flickering effect is due to the difference between your element height (`30px`) and the offsets you've given for the background (`-200px` -> `0px`).

Basically, it's scrolling past the view six times in the one second transition (because 30 goes into 200 six times), which is what is giving you the flickering effect. You can see the effect more easily if you increase the transition time a bit, say to 5 seconds; this will make it more obvious what it happening. (obviously you can set it back when you're done testing)

If you change the inital `background-position` to `-30px` instead of `-200px`, you'll get it scrolling into view just one time, and thus no flicker.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Shit I just missed the answer, 3 mins late :D

Comment: See, I figured this would not be a problem seeing as I'm working in a responsive design and the element would never exceed 200px. Your suggestion works perfectly, but I have my background showing if I use percentages (-100%) -- is that normal ?

Comment: Yes - backgrounds are a little tricky in that `X%` means that the line through the top `X%` of the image is the same as the line passing through `X%` of the element. This means `0%` corresponds to "top aligns to top", `50%` means "middle aligns to middle", `100%` means "bottom aligns to bottom", and everything else comes in between. In this case, because the background image is the same size as the element (that's how gradients work unless explicity-defined otherwise) then it doesn't matter what percentage you use, you will always get the same position.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is background-repeat. You must set it to no-repeat so that the background is not visible before hover

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9K2h/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, the problem is `background-repeat` and your very large background position.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aR9YV/1/) is an updated Fiddle with what I believe you were trying to achieve.

Note that I have removed all of the redundant CSS rules - all major browsers now support [gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) and [transitons](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) without prefix, making all those prefixes useless (it should also be noted that `-ms-transition` and `-ms-linear-gradient` have never existed, because IE didn't jump the gun... did you know there are at least THREE different ways to define gradients in Chrome?)

In addition to cleaning up, I moved the background definition to the element's styles (rather than its hover styles) to ensure that a "transition out" is possible, otherwise it just snaps to blank. I have applied `background-repeat:repeat-x` to only allow horizontal repeating, and adjusted the `background-position` so that in the initial state the gradient is just barely completely off the bottom, and the hover state is such that it is in the right place. This produces a smooth and exact transition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since IE11 is very recent, many users have not upgraded to this version. In fact, my target audience does need older version support (still nearly 20% use IE8 or 9), so I'm still using the script as generated by Colorzilla (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: My Fiddle works fine in IE10. Anyone using older than that is deliberately ignoring Windows Update, so why waste time on them? Besides, it's not the end of the world if they don't get a fancy gradient.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the `-ms-` prefixes *did* exist, but only for the IE10 preview releases. So for all intents and purposes you're right, they aren't necessary, but saying they never existed isn't quite accurate.